# List number of jobs of each status

Tags: slurm

Is there a simple way to get SLURM to print out, for a given user, the number of jobs of each status (e.g., running, pending, completed, failed, etc.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to get that information is with:

```
squeue -u $USER -o%T -ST | uniq -c
```

The `-u` argument will filter jobs for the specific user, the `-o%T` argument will only output the job state, and the `-S` argument will sort them. Then `uniq -c` will do the counting.

Example output:

```
$ squeue -u $USER -o%T -ST | uniq -c
    147 PENDING
     49 RUNNING
```

Comment: Perfect. I'll surely be using this almost daily.